# Variable not holding its value

Tags: c, gcc

In the following code snip, for some reason the value of eror isn't holding outside the FOR loop.

```
    eror = 0 ;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        predict = intercept + (slope * data[i][0]) ;
        printf("In the FOR loop eror =  %lf\n", eror) ;
        eror +=(data[i][1] - predict) ;
    }
    printf("Out of FOR loop eror = %lf\n", eror) ;
```

Some of the output is...

```
    In the FOR loop eror =  -0.028400
    In the FOR loop eror =  -0.011216
    In the FOR loop eror =  0.012196
    In the FOR loop eror =  0.019527
    In the FOR loop eror =  0.024293
    In the FOR loop eror =  0.021309
    In the FOR loop eror =  0.013337
    Out of FOR loop eror = -0.000000
```

Can anyone explain why there is a value inside the FOR loop, but not once the variable eror exits the FOR loop?

Comment: There **is** a value once it exits the for loop. The value is -0.000000

Comment: Put the first `printf` after `eror +=(data[i][1] - predict) ;`, probably you will have the same value printed two times (one IN and one OUT the cycle)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response :)

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're doing, this is expected: if slope and intercept are correct the average error (and therefore the sum of errors) should be 0

Comment: Perhaps you could do the calculation by hand (or on a calculator) and see what answer you get, and whether the computer gets the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
eror = 0 ;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    predict = intercept + (slope * data[i][0]) ;
    eror +=(data[i][1] - predict) ;
    printf("In the FOR loop eror =  %lf\n", eror) ;
}
printf("Out of FOR loop eror = %lf\n", eror) ;
```